# How to generate dropdownlist in asp.net MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In my razor I am generating dropdown list like this.

```
    @{
        var listItems = new List<ListItem> 
        { 
              new ListItem { Text = "Home To School", Value = "0" }, 
              new ListItem { Text = "School To Home", Value = "1" } 
        };
    }

@Html.DropDownList("Direction", new SelectList(listItems),new {onchange = "getAlldata()"})
```

HTML generated from this is like this

```
<select id="Direction" name="Direction" onchange="getAlldata()">
<option>Home To School</option>
<option>School To Home</option>
</select>
```

but I want to generate HTML something like this

```
<select id="Direction" name="Direction" onchange="getAlldata()">
<option value="0">Home To School</option>
<option value="1">School To Home</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use it like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Direction", new SelectList(listItems , "Value" , "Text"),new {onchange = "getAlldata()"})
```

Comment: Where do you put the definition of the function "getAlldata()" ?

Comment: Or simply `@Html.DropDownList("Direction", llistItems, new {onchange = "getAlldata()"})` - its pointless extra ovrhead to create a second `SelectList` from the existing one

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists) are some examples of how to build `DropDownList` with Razor, like one with using `SelectListItem`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var db = new NorthwindEntities();
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Categories
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                   {
                     Value = c.CategoryID.ToString(), 
                     Text = c.CategoryName
                   });
  ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
  return View();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Check this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Direction", new List<SelectListItem>
{
  new SelectListItem{ Text = "Home To School", Value = "0" },
  new SelectListItem{ Text = "School To Home", Value = "1" } 
},new {onchange = "getAlldata()"})
```

Comment: I have to generate my dropdown list in view only. Also It is static as shown in my question.

Comment: @vaibhavshah It was just an example of using collection of `SelectListItem` qouted from the article to show one way of doing this, I don't understand the -1. I added another way adapted to your data now.

Comment: @vaibhavshah Could you please explain this -1? I gave you article with different answers for this issue and quoted one of them. I see no reason of downvoting.

Comment: Where does the definition of getAlldata() go?