# LINQ Inner Join and Select Item Dropdown

Tags: linq, razor

I want to pull results from a database into a select dropdownbox. What I want to do is have a select dropdown box that shows the selected value that is in the database along with the other values in the list. The field CommDeptID and DeptText in the CommDept Table has values in it like 1 HR, 2 Administration, 3 IT etc. LocationID equals CommDeptID.

I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to 'IntranetSite.Models.Communications'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Communications is my Model That looks like this:

```
[Key]
public int CommunicationsID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Location")]
public int LocationID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Message Type")]
public int MessageTypeID { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Message")]
public string Message { get; set; }
public DateTime EnteredDateTime { get; set; }
```

LocationID is a field in my Communications table and a field in my CommDept Table.

```
    [Key]
    public int CommDeptID { get; set; }
    public string DeptText { get; set; }
```

My code:

```
var data = from c in _Context.Communications
           join d in _Context.CommDept on c.LocationID equals d.CommDeptID
           where c.CommunicationsID == id
           select new
                  {
                      c.CommunicationsID,
                      c.Title,
                      c.MessageTypeID,
                      c.Message,
                      c.LocationID,
                      d.DeptText
                  };

Communications = data;

LocationID = _Context.CommDept
                     .Select(a => new SelectListItem
                                      {
                                           Value = a.CommDeptID.ToString(),
                                           Text = a.DeptText,
                                           Selected = a.CommDeptID == c.LocationID
                                      })
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: What type is `Communications`? Please add the type to your question. Same for `LocationID`.

Comment: @GertArnold I updated the description with the answers to your questions

Comment: So do you understand why you can't assign `data` to it? Also, where would `DeptText` fit in a `Communications` instance?

Comment: @GertArnold What I am ultimately doing is pulling results from a database that allows the user to update any values that are incorrect. What i want to do is have a select dropdown box that shows the selected value that is in the database along with the other values in the list. The field CommDeptID and DeptText in the CommDept Table has values in it like 1 HR, 2 Administration, 3 IT etc. LocationID equals CommDeptID.

Comment: You're programming in C#. That presupposes a minimal understanding of classes, type instances, type safety etc. I'm in no way trying to be rude, but if you don't understand the basics, asking questions at Stack Overflow is bound to be a fruitless effort. I have no idea how to guide you any further, because you don't seem to understand my two simple questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select new statement is creating a new anonymous type. Then you are trying to implicitly cast that into the Communications model. Instead of just saying select new, try to select a new instance of the specific type instead of an anonymous type.

Another issue is that you are not using the data returned from the Linq statement. And then you are trying to use the alias c from the top linq query in a new statement. I would combine them into one statement.

Assuming LocationID is a SelectList, try the following:

```
var myList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>{
    from c in _Context.Communications
        join d in _Context.CommDept
        on c.LocationID equals d.CommDeptID
        where c.CommunicationsID == id
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = d.CommDeptID.ToString(),
            Text = d.DeptText,
            Selected = d.CommDeptID == c.LocationID
        }
    }.ToList());
```

I didn't run this myself, so double-check the code. You can see more information here too: [How to generate dropdownlist in asp.net MVC razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099258/how-to-generate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Comment: I get an error message 'SelectList' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: I had a feeling I had some syntax errors. I modified the answer to fix. It should work for you.

Comment: I am getting an error The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Change the a to a d. I just coped from your original post so I missed the change in the alias.

Comment: I get an error SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'ToList

Comment: I edited the code block again. The ToList() was in the wrong spot.